# Django - create a new instance of a model

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-2.7

**Answer**

As Sergey pointed out, **class Model(**kwargs)** is invalid, and is a typo in Django documentation. 
The "class" part comes from the markup they used when they wrote it.

So, what they actually meant in the Django documentation is:

> Creating objects
>
> To create a new instance of a model, just instantiate it like any
>   other Python class:
>
> **Model(**kwargs)**
>
> The keyword arguments are simply the names of the fields you’ve
>   defined on your model. Note that instantiating a model in no way
>   touches your database; for that, you need to save().

**Original question**


I found the following while reading the  [Django Docs about Model instances](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/instances/):

> Creating objects
>
> To create a new instance of a model, just instantiate it like any
>   other Python class:
>
> class Model(**kwargs)
>
> The keyword arguments are simply the names of the fields you’ve
>   defined on your model. Note that instantiating a model in no way
>   touches your database; for that, you need to save().

What is the difference between these two codes?

```
class Model(**kwargs)
new_model = Model(**kwargs)
```

I know the second one creates a new instance of the class Model, with kwargs.
Is the first one different from it? To me, it seems like it rather redefines the Model class.

Comment: The first one is incorrect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`class Model(**kwargs)` is not a [valid Python syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance), the latter would look like

```
class Model(SomeBaseClass):
    pass
```

Judging by the formatting (the line looks like a subheading), this must be a mistake in the Django documentation.

If you look at the [Sphinx source of the page](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/docs/ref/models/instances.txt), you'll see that the "class" thing is actually a part of Sphinx markup. What they meant is

> To create a new instance of a model, just instantiate it like any
>   other Python class:
>
> ```
> Model(**kwargs)
> ```
>
> The keyword arguments are simply the names of the fields you've
>   defined on your model.

Comment: Thank you, Sergey, I appreciate you took the time to write a clear answer on the question.

Answer (score 0):

The first line defines a class.
The second line defines an instance of a class.

Comment: The first line is invalid.

Comment: Yes, I know, but not to be to rude, obviously the OP has absolutely NO IDEA what OOP is.

Comment: Brandon, I'm in the process of learning about OOP, and my question to me is part of this process. For what I have learnt, in Python we define a class by "class ClassName(AncestorName): class_definition" and create an instance of a class by "ClassName(**kwargs)". What my question referred to was something I hadn't seen before. I searched it on the web and on SO, and since I didn't find an answer, I asked it here. If it really is a typo in Django documentation, then I believe that my question will be useful for anyone who may get confused by it. Anyway, I will edit it with the answer.

Comment: Sorry to be curt, but you really should get familiar with the basics of Python before diving into Django. Defining and instantiating classes is Python 101.

Comment: I'm working on it, man. But, regardless of my knowledge, I still believe the question (completed with the answer) will be useful for anyone who runs into such a typo.

Comment: Agreed. Again, sorry to come off as a grumpy bastard :)

Comment: No worries, man. I appreciate you take your time for the question.